# Which clang-tidy checks provide automated fixes?

Tags: c++, automated-refactoring, clang-tidy

I'd like to find out which of the clang-tidy checks are possible to run with the -fix option, i.e. automatically generate fixed code.
I know all the modernize-* checks can do this and some other checks can too (like google-readability-casting) but nowhere did I find a complete list.
Is there a list somewhere? Or a method to find out other than reading the source of each and every check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since clang-tidy 10 the fix option is included in the list of checks in the [documentation.](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/list.html)

The rest of my answer is still valid for versions 9 and lower.

---

`grep --include=\*.cpp -rc './' -e "FixItHint"|grep -v ':0$' > FixItChecks.txt`

I ran this grep command in the clang-tidy source directory. It counts the number of occurences of "FixItHint" string in all .cpp files and filters out files with zero occurences.

`clang::FixItHint` is a class that (according to documentation):

> Annotates a diagnostic with some code that should be inserted, removed, or replaced to fix the problem.

I admit the method to obtain the list is somewhat crude however I did check multiple files and the results seem to be correct.

The cleaned-up and sorted list of checks with fixes:

```
abseil/StringFindStartswithCheck
android/CloexecCheck
boost/UseToStringCheck
bugprone/ArgumentCommentCheck
bugprone/BoolPointerImplicitConversionCheck
bugprone/CopyConstructorInitCheck
bugprone/InaccurateEraseCheck
bugprone/MacroParenthesesCheck
bugprone/MisplacedOperatorInStrlenInAllocCheck
bugprone/MoveForwardingReferenceCheck
bugprone/ParentVirtualCallCheck
bugprone/StringIntegerAssignmentCheck
bugprone/SuspiciousMemsetUsageCheck
bugprone/SuspiciousSemicolonCheck
bugprone/SuspiciousStringCompareCheck
bugprone/UnusedRaiiCheck
bugprone/VirtualNearMissCheck
cert/PostfixOperatorCheck
cppcoreguidelines/ProBoundsConstantArrayIndexCheck
cppcoreguidelines/ProTypeCstyleCastCheck
cppcoreguidelines/ProTypeMemberInitCheck
cppcoreguidelines/ProTypeStaticCastDowncastCheck
fuchsia/DefaultArgumentsCheck
fuchsia/RestrictSystemIncludesCheck
google/AvoidCStyleCastsCheck
google/ExplicitConstructorCheck
google/ExplicitMakePairCheck
google/GlobalVariableDeclarationCheck
google/TodoCommentCheck
llvm/IncludeOrderCheck
llvm/TwineLocalCheck
misc/DefinitionsInHeadersCheck
misc/RedundantExpressionCheck
misc/StaticAssertCheck
misc/UniqueptrResetReleaseCheck
misc/UnusedAliasDeclsCheck
misc/UnusedParametersCheck
misc/UnusedUsingDeclsCheck
modernize/AvoidBindCheck
modernize/DeprecatedHeadersCheck
modernize/LoopConvertCheck
modernize/MakeSmartPtrCheck
modernize/PassByValueCheck
modernize/RawStringLiteralCheck
modernize/RedundantVoidArgCheck
modernize/ReplaceAutoPtrCheck
modernize/ReplaceRandomShuffleCheck
modernize/ReturnBracedInitListCheck
modernize/ShrinkToFitCheck
modernize/UnaryStaticAssertCheck
modernize/UseAutoCheck
modernize/UseBoolLiteralsCheck
modernize/UseDefaultMemberInitCheck
modernize/UseEmplaceCheck
modernize/UseEqualsDefaultCheck
modernize/UseEqualsDeleteCheck
modernize/UseNoexceptCheck
modernize/UseNullptrCheck
modernize/UseOverrideCheck
modernize/UseTransparentFunctorsCheck
modernize/UseUncaughtExceptionsCheck
modernize/UseUsingCheck
objc/PropertyDeclarationCheck
performance/FasterStringFindCheck
performance/ForRangeCopyCheck
performance/InefficientAlgorithmCheck
performance/InefficientVectorOperationCheck
performance/MoveConstArgCheck
performance/TypePromotionInMathFnCheck
performance/UnnecessaryCopyInitialization
performance/UnnecessaryValueParamCheck
readability/AvoidConstParamsInDecls
readability/BracesAroundStatementsCheck
readability/ContainerSizeEmptyCheck
readability/DeleteNullPointerCheck
readability/IdentifierNamingCheck
readability/ImplicitBoolConversionCheck
readability/InconsistentDeclarationParameterNameCheck
readability/MisplacedArrayIndexCheck
readability/NamedParameterCheck
readability/NamespaceCommentCheck
readability/NonConstParameterCheck
readability/RedundantControlFlowCheck
readability/RedundantDeclarationCheck
readability/RedundantFunctionPtrDereferenceCheck
readability/RedundantMemberInitCheck
readability/RedundantSmartptrGetCheck
readability/RedundantStringCStrCheck
readability/RedundantStringInitCheck
readability/SimplifyBooleanExprCheck
readability/SimplifySubscriptExprCheck
readability/StaticAccessedThroughInstanceCheck
readability/StaticDefinitionInAnonymousNamespaceCheck
readability/StringCompareCheck
readability/UniqueptrDeleteReleaseCheck
```