# How do tools like clang-tidy or cppcheck compare to klocwork?

Tags: static-analysis, cppcheck, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy, klocwork

Is there a fundamental difference between these tools? After all, klocwork is relatively expensive and the other ones are free? Both do static code analysis after some rules.

Are there differences in the quality of rules? Does it only depend on the rules? What is your experience?

Answer (score 4):

You get what you pay for, both in the depth of the checkers, and in defect tracking and false-positive suppression.  cppcheck and the Clang static analyzer are worth running, and find a reasonable number of shallow but serious bugs, even in a good codebase.  (We run the Clang analyzer first, with the settings file turned to the max with help from https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeWarnings.  cppcheck occasionally finds some bugs missed by it, but similar in character.)

Klocwork, and its rival Coverity, both find much deeper bugs in C/C++, sometimes breathtaking in their depth of analysis.  Coverity, though, has been taken over by Synopsys, and made little progress in its C/C++ checkers in the last decade; but they are still worth running.  (Their JVM checkers are not.)  I haven’t used Klocwork recently, but they also are no longer independent.  (See my Dr Dobbs article for more detail, http://www.drdobbs.com/testing/deploying-static-analysis/240003801)

Later:  Dr Dobbs has joined the choir invisible; the full issue PDF is still available at http://twimgs.com/ddj/digital/072312/DDD_0712.pdf.  My unabridged preprint, with references, is at https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.11861.
Internet Archive links: sections [1](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915004319/https://www.drdobbs.com/testing/deploying-static-analysis/240003801), [2](http://web.archive.org/web/20150901084604/https://www.drdobbs.com/testing/deploying-static-analysis/240003801?pgno=2), and [3](http://web.archive.org/web/20150901084607/https://www.drdobbs.com/testing/deploying-static-analysis/240003801?pgno=3).

I’ve since done a free trial of Klocwork’s C++ checkers; despite their takeover by Perforce, they are still serious about supporting the product, unlike Synopsys.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed my error accordingly. Btw. commenting my post or suggesting an edit would be a more appropriate place for suggesting a fix than placing it in your answer. Anyway, nice answer, upvoting.

Comment: Klockwork has taken over Coverity? Did you check the magic quadrant for static analysis. Coverity (Synopsys) is at the top, others are far behind, and Klockwork is not even mentioned. https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/assets/security/magic-quadrant-for-application-security-testing

Comment: > “Klockwork has taken over Coverity?”  No.  > “Did you check the magic quadrant for static analysis.”  No, generally not impressed by Gartner in this area.  > “Klockwork is not even mentioned.”  Likewise.

Comment: Sounds like a promising article to read - sadly i think the article have been rewoked. Is there an update or perhaps some alternative reading that you might suggest?

Answer (score 1):

LLVM has a tool for static analysis called [Clang static analyzer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangStaticAnalyzer.html).

Clang static analyzer and cppcheck are open-source (allowing you to write your own checks/modify existing ones) vs klockwork being proprietary (has an API to write your own checks).

As for the quality of the checks - you'll have to try for yourself, I'm trying to base this answer on facts, not opinions. Nothing prevents you from using more than one static analysis tool though.

Clang-tidy is a little different, it calls itself a "linter" tool and while it can be used for static analysis it also provides automated fixes for some of the defects it can find. Internally clang-tidy uses an abstract syntax tree to represent your code. In order to build this AST the code has to be compile-able by clang which can be a (possibly major) drawback in some codebases.

For list of clang-tidy checks that provide automated fixes see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51507092/9874699).

Answer (score 1):

I believe clang-tidy or cppcheck engine does line by line analysis. Klocwork engine in other hand, does inter procedural analysis. Klocwork can detect file dependent issues as well what most of other tool cant detect. Klocwork is very powerful in finding critical detects like memory leaks, Buffer Overflow, NULL exceptions, Dead Lock, concurrency issues, etc..,

we have evaluated multiple Static code analysers and ended with Klocwork.

I will tell you why we have chosen Klocwork than any other SCA tools,

1. Number of Checkers to detect possible vulnerabilities. Klocwork has
   more than 1000+ checkers to detect coding defects/issues.
2. Klocwork can work at developer desktop. So it makes the code bug
   free at the time of development. (It has post check-in capability as
   well)
3. klocwork has direct plugin available for Visual Studio, Eclipse,
   Intellij IDEA, Wind River, CCS and Eclipse based IDEs. Klocwork has
   its own IDE as well. (If you are using any other IDEs than what
   Klocwork plugin supports, you can use Klocwork IDE. Klocwork IDE can
   work with any Editor or IDE you have)
4. Klocwork supports checking almost all industry standards like Misra,
   Autosar, CERT, CWE, DISA-STIG, OWASP, etc..,
5. You can write your own checkers in Klocwork to maintain/check your
   internal coding guidelines.
6. Effectiveness in finding the Vulnerabilities issues .
7. Reporting and Metrics (100+ reporting formats and 400+ metrics)
8. Filtering the issues – remove 3rd party code in report, create
   module report, team report, etc..,
9. Fast – Though they create AST based on your native build settings
   still Klocwork engine is fast and effective.
10. Automation – Automation – Automation. Klocwork build can be
     automated as it has rich command line tools. Plus, Klocwork has
     direct plugin available for Jenkins and Teamcity.
11. Simple Deployment – Client server architecture
12. Documentation – Documentation and Demo videos of Klocwork is
     available online (Open). You just open google and say, “Klocwork C
     and C++ checker list” you will get the list of Klocwork checkers
     with proper explanation.
13. Support – Klocwork support team is very user friendly.
14. Licensing – Simple licensing. No hidden charges.

I would say, take up a free evaluation of Klocwork and test it on your project. I am sure you will love it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a fundamental difference between the clang-tidy or cppcheck compare to klocwork.

Klocwork wrapper will watch your build and creates build specification file based on your compiler name build settings including customized system calls. using this build spec file Klocwork does interprocedural analysis and creates abstract syntax three in back end. then it will try to cover 100% code and 100% path. So Klocwork analysis will be more accurate and it can detect the real defects in the code.

Klocwork can detect data flow issues as well.